# Is there any function like iconv in Python?

Tags: python, encoding

I have some CSV files need to convert from shift-jis to utf-8.

Here is my code in PHP, which is successful transcode to readable text.

```
$str = utf8_decode($str);
$str = iconv('shift-jis', 'utf-8'. '//TRANSLIT', $str);
echo $str;
```

My problem is how to do same thing in Python.

Comment: `utf8_decode` on a Shift-JIS encoded string?! That makes no sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know PHP, but does this work :

```
mystring.decode('shift-jis').encode('utf-8') ?
```

Also I assume the CSV content is from a file. There are a few options for opening a file in python.

```
with open(myfile, 'rb') as fin
```

would be the first and you would get data as it is

```
with open(myfile, 'r') as fin
```

would be the default file opening

Also I tried on my computed with a shift-js text and the following code worked :

```
with open("shift.txt" , "rb") as  fin :
    text = fin.read()

text.decode('shift-jis').encode('utf-8')
```

result was the following in UTF-8 (without any errors)

```
' \xe3\x81\xa6 \xe3\x81\xa7 \xe3\x81\xa8'
```

Ok I validate my solution :)

The first char is indeed the good character: "\xe3\x81\xa6" means "E3 81 A6"
It gives the correct result.

[image]

You can try yourself at this [URL](http://www.endmemo.com/unicode/unicodeconverter.php)

Comment: Thanks. I tried that already, but i have no idea to solve the error.

UnicodeEncodeError: 'shift_jis' codec can't encode character u'\x83' in position 191: illegal multibyte sequence

If i added 
`text.replace(u'\x83', u'\'')`
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 191: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Thank you so much for helpful reply. Finally I find out the problem, which the CSV file needs utf-8 decode before shift-jis to utf-8. So `mystring.decode('shift-jis').encode('utf-8')` is WORK for me. Thanks again. :)

Comment: I realized is source file problem. Here is my solution.
`text = text.decode('utf-8').encode('iso-8859-1')`
`text = text.decode('shift-jis').encode('utf-8')`

Comment: This answer works fine for transforming strings between encodings, but iconv can also do more than just that, for example you can use it to transliterate characters, as asked by OP. The `//TRANSLIT` will cause characters that can't be represented by the target encoding to be substituted by something meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

for when pythons built-in encodings are insufficient there's an `iconv` at PyPi.

```
pip install iconv
```

unfortunately the documentation is nonexistant.

There's also `iconv_codecs`

```
pip install iconv_codecs
```

eg:

```
>>> import iconv_codecs
>>> iconv_codecs.register('ansi_x3.110-1983')
>>> "foo".encode('ansi_x3.110-1983')
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could post the string that you are trying to convert since this error suggest some problem with the in-data, older versions of PHP failed silently on broken input strings which makes this hard to diagnose.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html) this might also be due to differences in shift-jis dialects, try using 'shift_jisx0213' or 'shift_jis_2004' instead.

If using another dialect does not work you might get away with asking python to fail silently by using `.decode('shift-jis','ignore')` or `.decode('shift-jis','replace')` .